# Is asking to translate a short paragraph from English to Portuguese on topic here?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic-definition

I want to see if I'm allowed to ask such a question in the main site?

> Would you please translate the following paragraphs into Portuguese?
>
> - a proposal for creating a remote sensing and photogrammeetry Q&A site    in StackExchange Network is in commitment phase now
> - All the instructions you need to know to be an effective committer to    the remote sensing and photogrammetry proposal in StackExchange
> - You can also have a look at the homepage and the "definition phase is    over!" page of this google site.
> - There I've summarized all the efforts from last year and also have    linked  to valuable tutorials which introduce the StackExchange
>     network and make you more familiar with what I'm trying to do
> - Let's make a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry real. Let's all press "commit" button!
> - Please share or like the post as much as possible. This will help it    be seen on more news feeds and it will likely be seen by more
>     interested people.
> - Please share the page and invite others to like it in order to have more committers and probably a successful launch
>
> I need them to post about [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90327/remote-sensing-and-photogrammetry?referrer=8G2asYAyI_To9RoVf1VtPg2) in facebook pages that
>   are related to the topic and promote it. Because as you know and as
>   facebook suggests, posts in local languages receive more likes and
>   more attention and so they might be seen by more people.
>
> Hint: I just want those bulleted paragraphs in Portuguese not more.

Comment: See also [this question about translations from German](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/263/pode-se-pedir-tradu%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-alem%C3%A3o). The focus of the answers there is somewhat different, but the gist of it is that you can ask (in English or Portuguese) how to express an idea (such as would be expressed in a word or phrase) in idiomatic Portuguese. I agree with @JorgeB that translating whole texts is off-topic.

Comment: @Lambie for me? (Because sometimes our relatives who have been successful to escape iran, think that paying through paypal for us will make legal problems for us) What does that mean? It means that when I wanted to pay 5000 yen to RESTEC (Remote Sensing Technology Center of Japan), no exchange center within Iran did the job for me. What does that mean? It means that do you think in a country with a government which believes that English is not necessary to be taught at schools, I can find a professional portuguese translator? Any way, it took me a lot of time to do the job but it was done at

Comment: @Lambie last and I really don't want to come beg here. I'm not happy with my government and one of my wishes is just to escape Iran. But you see, thanks to my government's meaningless enmity with the west, they are not willing to accept iranian people in their country. It is not imaginable for you, but I wish that I didn't know persian because each day I get up and start to check the news, I see some of those foolish people who are threatening Trump and are advising him to alleviate the situation in his poverty-stricken country and this is when they even couldn't rescue our brave firefighters

Comment: @Lambie a week ago. Each year in February they arrange an exhibition to show the world that people within Iran hate america and israel while people within Iran hate government policy. These were the reasons which made me request translation here while I am familiar with international sites like gengo.com, etc which can do a translation for me in a much lesser time. I really do love to pay for every service that I'm receiving. I really do love to be able to exchange knowledge easily and internationally. But that is the situation and I understood and will never request any translation again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, translation requests are not on-topic.

If you try to translate them yourself and want help with corrections or improvements on that work, I think that *might* be on-topic too.
I would accept it, but I'm not sure about others.

If you want help with "*how to express an idea in idiomatic Portuguese*", that **is** on-topic.

---

If you want help in understanding those sentences, you can ask in [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) or [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) (I'm not sure which).

---

From the help centre's article on [`What topics can I ask about here?`](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> #### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> (...)
>
> - The meaning of a word or expression in context (if it is not clear from the dictionary definition)
>
> (...)
>
> #### What about translations?
>
> We are not a translation service, nor do we purport to be experts in languages other than Portuguese. Asking about the meaning of a difficult Portuguese sentence is fine. So is asking how to express an idea in idiomatic Portuguese. But please don't ask us to translate a text to or from another language.

Comment: thanks a lot. I had the same question is [spanish se](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2512/13791) and they advised me to ask in the chat room. Am I allowed to do the same in the italian chat room, providing my explanations in the comments of the above link?

Comment: @sepideh You can always try, I suppose, but you may not get very good Portuguese by asking in the Italian chat room. :)

Comment: @tchrist oh sorry, it was a copy and paste :)

Comment: @sepideh ahahahah I was thinking what is the sense of this comment?

Comment: But yes, @sepideh, the chat room seems perfect for that.